# Image zooming on mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Im using  [touchpanview](http://www.consulenza-web.com/jquery/touchpanview/) to have zoomable images on a mobile application im building using jquery mobile 1.3.

The Problem I have is with an image that is zoomable you, you can scroll the image as intended, but cannot scroll the page. So if you scroll down to the image you cannot scroll back up because the plugin takes over control on the image. I have seen similar plugins in use on other mobile sites such as tesco and thredless but cannot seem to find a similar one.

Has anyone else over come this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably preventing default actions when you 'touch' the image.

Is there anyway that you can have a preview of the image seperate to the zoomable image then 'click' to enable the zooming function then 'click' again to disable the plugin and return the preview image up.

Essentially having two divs and hiding and displaying them.

Comment: Yes, will work nicely thanks, I am targeting double tap to do this using this plugin https://gist.github.com/tlync/1016011  (recommended by the zoom plugin). I have implemented it like this but it seems to be fires twice :

$('#image img').on('double tap', function () {
  alert('tap');
});

Comment: Resolved it, my implmention of the doubletap was in correct, should have been   
$('#image img').doubletap(function(e){
                        $('#image').hide();
                        $('#preview').show();
                      });